# Distance in coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems

The line $y = \frac{3}{4}x + m$, where $m\ne0$ , intersects the $x$-axis at point $P$ and the $y$-axis at $Q$.

Which is larger:

- Quantity 1 : The distance from $P$ to the origin $( 0 , 0)$
- Quantity 2 : The distance from $Q$ to the origin $( 0 , 0)$

I don't know how to approach this question

/ Daniel M

Comment: What's the distance formula?

Comment: d = sqrt root of (x2-x1) to the power of 2 + (y2-y1) to the power of 2

Comment: Can you find an expression for the $x$ and $y$ intercepts of $y=\frac 34x + m$?  As in $P=(?,?)$ and $Q=(?,?)$.

Comment: Since your point P and Q are on the axis, you can simplify your distance formula

Comment: Yes but then I just get that the distance from Q to origo is y and that from p to origo is x. How can that help me get the ansver?

Answer (score 2):

setting $y=0$ we get $$x=-\frac{4m}{3}$$in the other case we get $$y=m$$ the distances are $\frac{4}{3}|m|>|m|$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Any line given by $y=ax+b$ intersects the $x$-axis in $(-\frac{b}{a},0)$ and the $y$-axis in $(0,b)$.

Using that, you just need to compute distances of both points to the origin. Note that, since they have one coordinate equal to 0, the distance will be the absolute value of the non-zero one.